# Residue integral over an arc

Tags: complex-integration, classical-mechanics

I want to evaluate the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sqrt{A-\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2\theta}-\frac{\beta}{\sin^2\theta}} d\theta,
\end{equation}
where $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ are the roots of the expression inside the square root $A-\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2\theta}-\frac{\beta}{\sin^2\theta}$. (The problem comes from evaluating action-angle variables on a classical mechanics problem).

I have found a solution by making a complicated change of variables (see equation (18) on https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0464.pdf). What I was thinking is if it is possible to evaluate the integral by the residues method, doing the typical change of variables $z=e^{i\theta}$, $dz=izd\theta$ thus turning the expression
\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{A-\frac{\alpha}{\cos^2\theta}-\frac{\beta}{\sin^2\theta}} d\theta = \sqrt{\frac{A}{z^2}-\frac{4\alpha}{(z^2+1)^2} +\frac{4\beta}{(z^2-1)^2}} dz
\end{equation}
and then applying the residues theorem.

The problem is that, since the first integral is considered over a certain angle (smaller than $2\pi$ since the integral would diverge) can I pick a special contour on which this method would make sense?

Comment: That is pretty much an elliptic integral, how do you plan to apply the residue theorem since the endpoints of the integration range are not fixed?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's the main problem and why I am asking. If I integrate the last expression on the contour unit circle I get the same result as with the other method (if I didn't do any computation wrong), but in the first integral you can't avoid points where it diverges. That's why I was thinking if maybe there is a way to use the residue theorem in this case or if anyone knows a way to compute this integral without using that "magical" change of variables from the reference I posted.

Comment: Where will the roots of the expression inside the surd locate after the transformation to z? (I am not totally desperate about solving the problem with residue theorem)

Comment: @Szeto Somewhere in the unit circle depending on the values of $A$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @G.Gallego Umm...if you scale the variable by some factor, thus changing the size of the contour, would the roots become out of the circle?

Comment: @G.Gallego And are you certain that the roots are inside the circle? If yes, then I have very little hope...

Comment: @Szeto Ah ok, you meant the roots of the expression in z. Anyway the problem is with the integration limits, since the first one doesn't go from 0 to $2\pi$ the integral after the change will only go on a partial arc, not on the whole circle.

Comment: @G.Gallego As you know, the roots of the expression inside the surd are the problematic branch points. I think the branch points lie on the unit circle, which gives me some hope. People often think the integration limits is a problem. Well, I have a small trick to tackle arc integrals of arbitrary angles. I will try it out later.

Comment: @Szeto Oh yes, you are right. I just calculated the roots when all parameters are equal to 1 and they are not in the unit circle.

Comment: @G.Gallego I think the location of branch points can be solely determined by $\theta_1,\theta_2$, not related to the parameters.

Comment: @Szeto But the thetas are determined by the parameters...

Comment: Maybe is it possible, if z1 and z2 are the limits of the integral, draw a line that encloses those and all the other roots but doesn't enclose any of the poles in a way that the integrand is single valued outside that curve? If that is possible, then we can apply the residue theorem outside the curve.

Comment: @G.Gallego I derived an answer $(\theta_1-\theta_2)\sqrt{A}$. I took a look at the paper, but there are too many strange variables that I don’t have time to look into. However, with respect to how complicated the given answer is, I believe my answer is wrong.

Comment: Maybe simply this integral is not something for residue theorem...